# How to read dynamic input in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form which creates dynamic inputs. I need to be able to pick them up by the controller but it only takes the first input since it is not dynamic, from the first one they are all dynamic it does not work

**Form Html**

```
    <form  method="get" action="{{route('albaran_entrada_create')}}">
     <input class="form-control widthInput2 precio"  id="precio-{{$num}}" name="precio-{{$num}}" type="number" value="0">
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Crear Albaran entrada">
    </form>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function albaran_entrada_create(Request $request){

    $precio1=$request->precio-1;  // no dynamic
    $precio2=$request->precio-2;  //  yes dynamic


    Log::info($precio1); //good
    Log::info($precio2); //bad

}
```

PD: if I pass the form via ajax will it work?

Comment: can you post your HTML and ajax code also

Comment: The short answer is : Yes.

Comment: in ajax I have not done it, I have passed it in the traditional way

Comment: ok @TALHa F 
I was afraid that with ajax if it could

Comment: If you pass it, then It will work. Otherwise not.

Answer (score -1):

try to loop throw request inputs and get key and value of input

```
foreach ($request->except('_token') as $key => $value) {
    Log::info($key);
    Log::info($value);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your controller you could iterate over the number of form elements in your form ( if that count is available ) assigning your values to variable variables.

```
for($i=0; $i<$elements_count; $i++) {
  ${'precio'.$i} = $request->input('precio'.$i);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you use an array to send those inputs, it will make it easier to know wich number is present too

```html
<form  method="get" action="{{route('albaran_entrada_create')}}">
     <input class="form-control widthInput2 precio"  id="precio-{{$num}}" name="precio[{{$num}}]" type="number" value="0">
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Crear Albaran entrada">
</form>
```

Then in the controller, you just need to recover one input, the array

```php
public function albaran_entrada_create(Request $request){

    $precio = $request->input('precio', []);
    // example of result [1 => "precio 1 value", 4 => "precio 4 value"]
}
```

Comment: but what he needed @D.Simmons

Comment: It seems to me that it may be what I really need to try it, I tell you friend